# First metal detector by Alexander Graham Bell, how did it work?

Tags: history

> Alexander Graham Bell developed a similar device (metal detector) to
>   attempt to locate a bullet lodged in the chest of American President
>   James Garfield in 1881; the metal detector worked correctly but the
>   attempt was unsuccessful because the metal coil spring bed Garfield
>   was lying on confused the detector.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_detector).

But how did this early metal detector work? There was no vacuum tube or transistor available to build an oscillator or amplifier. I can't imagine such a detector using DC current only.

Did Bell use a mechanical DC/AC converter like an [induction coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_coil)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this document](https://web.phys.ksu.edu/mmmm/student/garfield.pdf):

> He knew that a metallic object near an inductor changes the value of
>   the inductance. If a listening device, such as a telephone, was
>   connected to an audio frequency source, the change in induction would
>   also change the audio signal. This change would be heard by the
>   listener. With Bell’s recent invention, the telephone, he thought that
>   he could hear that change.

...

> **Bell successfully detected bullets in sides of beef and shrapnel in
>   Civil War veterans.** He made several attempts with variations on the
>   basic apparatus to locate the bullet in the President’s body. **But, he
>   was unable to find the location of the bullet in Garfield.** The
>   physicians in attendance attempted to find the bullet by inserting
>   their fingers into the bullet hole. While the idea of sterilization
>   had been developed by Joseph Lister in England by this time, most
>   doctors in the United States did not take it seriously. Thus, on
>   September 19, 1881, eleven weeks after being shot President Garfield
>   died.

[Why didn't it work](http://telecom.csail.mit.edu/archives/history/bell-garfield-assasin.html)?

> The problem was the bed he was in. Coil spring mattresses had just
>   been invented. In fact, a national campaign hadn't even been started
>   yet at the time of the assassination. The White House was one of the
>   few that had the coil spring mattresses at the time. Very few people
>   had even heard of them. Thus, Bell's and Newcomb's invention was
>   detecting metal -- unfortunately they didn't realize that it was the
>   coil springs.

The first document gives details of the interruptor coil and ticking clock used by Bell to generate alternating current in the circuit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So my guess was right, Bell's metal detector was possible using AC only and a balanced bridge circuit. All without using a vacuum tube or transistor.

Comment: @Uwe note that before transistors and tubes, the common amplifier was the carbon microphone (invented by Edison iir?)  Play around with oldschool telephone parts, and quickly you'll find that they'll break into feedback oscillation just like any audio amp.  A carbon microphone is like a 3-terminal active component, but where the "input terminal" is the mechanical motions of the diaphragm.